# PyCharm says “Unable to display frame variables” in debug mode? (not related to gevent)

Tags: debugging, pycharm

PyCharm 2016.2.3 is displaying an error message while in debug mode:

```
Unable to display frame variables
```

Many others ask this question, and the answer has to do with 'gevent'  In my case I am not using gevent, and their fix has no effect.

How can I fix this?   (Enabling gevent compatibility has no effect)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this problem.  Reporting it here in case others have similar.

It seems a host of issues will get reported as Unable to Display Frame variables.

In my case it as a condition where the **str** method had infinite recursion.
I could see this by printing prior to getting to that step in the trace.
This generated an error with a stack trace allowing for meaningful debugging.